# Rails command doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ubuntu 12.04, `gem install rails` succeeds, but when I try `rails -v` I get an error message saying:

> The program rails is  currently not installed. You can install it by
>   ...

How can I get the `rails` command to work?

Comment: PLease show the actual output from the `gem install rails` command that succeeds.

Comment: Also, how did you install Ruby? Was it through RVM?

Comment: did you tried `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential` ..??

Comment: When I use `RVM` install Ruby, I have installed the dependent packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the following in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`, because in your solution you will need to write your `source ...` after every reboot:

```
# This loads RVM into a shell session.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: works fine just not in a specific directory, turned issue with running the binaries in a project upgraded from 2 to 4

Answer (score 0):

I've never had this problem, but for rails to be found, the rails binary file must be on the path.  That is, in a directory listed in the PATH environment variable.

To see the value of the PATH environment variable.

```
echo $PATH
env | grep PATH
```

You might try uninstalling rails, and then reinstalling.

Comment: I can found rails in .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.8-p286/bin, but I still can not run `rail -v` or `./rails -v` @Marlin Pierce

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!

I just type `source .rvm/scripts/rvm` in my HOME path, and it works!!!

Comment: Seems like someone didn't read the instructions that came up on screen when they installed RVM ;)